# I'm trying to make sense of session, but cannot get any data out of it

Tags: node.js, botframework, slack, azure-language-understanding

Currently using LUIS in a bot that connects to Slack. Right now I'm using interactive messages and trying to respond to user input correctly. When I click an item from the drop down LUIS receives it as a message. I can get the text with session.message.text, however I need to get the callback_id of the attachment as well as the channel it was sent from.

I've used `console.log(session)` to get an idea of what session looks like. From there I've seen that `session.message.sourceEvent` contains the data I need, however I can't use `indexOf()` or `contains()` to actual extrapolate the data. I've also tried `session.message.sourceEvent.Payload` but end up getting "[object [Object]]". I've tried searching for documentation on session formatting but to no avail.

Below is a snippet of what is returned when I run `console.log(session.message.sourceEvent)`.

```
 { Payload: 
     action_ts: '1513199773.200354',
     is_app_unfurl: false,
        subtype: 'bot_message',
     team: { id: 'T03QR2PHH', domain: 'americanairlines' },
     user: { id: 'U6DT58F2T', name: 'john.cerreta' },
     message_ts: '1513199760.000073',
     attachment_id: '1',
        ts: '1513199760.000073' },
     actions: [ [Object] ],
     callback_id: 'map_selection1',
     original_message: 
        username: 'Rallybot',
     response_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/actions/T03QR2PHH/287444348935/Y6Yye3ijlC6xfmn8qjMK4ttB',
        type: 'message',
   { type: 'interactive_message',
     channel: { id: 'G6NN0DT88', name: 'privategroup' },
     token: 'removed for security',
      { text: 'Please choose the Rally and Slack team you would like to map below.',
        bot_id: 'B7WDX03UM',
        attachments: [Array],
     trigger_id: '285857445393.3841091595.085028141d2b8190b38f1bf0ca47dd88' },
  ApiToken: 'removed for security' }
```

Comment: If Gary's answer below was helpful, don't forget to "accept" it. While this is not mandatory, it is a good way to thank people for the assistance they have given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session.message.sourceEvent` is a javascript `Object`, however `indexOf` or `contains` are functions of `String` or `Array` types.

Any info you required in the object, you should direct use the code `<object>.<key>` to invoke that value. You can try `session.message.sourceEvent.Payload.action_ts` for example.

Also, you can use `Object.keys(session.message.sourceEvent)` to get all the keys in this object.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to NodeJS and JavaScript as a whole and I think its showing!

Comment: @john-cerreta, it looks like solved your issue, right?

Comment: @gary-liu-msft it's helped me, however even with Object.keys I'm still unable to receive the channel.id. That's mostly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @gary-liu-msft is there any documentation on exactly what items are stored where in session? It seems like most of the info is gained by console.log() and then parsing through it by hand

Comment: You can refer to https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session.html for the
Bot Builder SDK Chat Reference Library